# (C++) assignment operator vs copy constructor: when is each used implicitly

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Please correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding is that a copy constructor is used when you do this:

```
myClass newInstant = oldInstant;
```

while an assignment operator is used when you do this:

```
myClass newInstant;
newInstant = oldInstant;
```

I believe both achieve the same result but the first is more direct because it avoid using a constructor first then copying over the new data.

What I am unsure of is this, when a function is passed an instant not by reference is it copied using the copy constructor or using the assignment operator. Additionally, which is used when returning an instant from the function.

In general, in which cases are the copy constructor and assignment operator used?

One last question, how would I return a value without copying it? If a returned instant is a copy and the old instant is deleted how would I get around this to be more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: copy constructor is used when a new instance is created using an existing one and assignment operator is used to overwrite an existing instance with another instance. So when something is passed to a function by value a new instance is created from an existing one, therefore ........ . If you want to avoid copies when returning by value try to ensure your code allows return value optimization or move whatever it is thats expensive to copy.

Comment: the "one last question" is a separate question. Please stick to 1 question per question. You should be able to find answers to that question by searching the site

Answer (score 3):

copy constructor is used when you initialize an object of an exisiting one like in your example:

```
vClass oldInstant;
yClass newInstant = oldInstant; // invoking copy constructor
```

assignment operator is used to assign something let's say an existing object to another one existing.

```
myClass newInstant; // invoking myClss constructor. so from now and on newInstant is already existing object;
newInstant = oldInstant; //oldInstant is also an already existing object. now assign one object to another. (assigning oldInstant to newInstant)
```

keep in mind that their use is completely different but each one has its own use.
*** sometimes we want to create an object and assign it another existing (copy constructor) because we may want to SAVE the original object and do something on the copy.

*** assignment operator we cannot avoid using it!! can you do some calculations in maths without equals operator '='???

things copy constructor and assignment operator should do:

*** copy constructor should use "deep copy" not "shallow copy" when there's some 
memory on the heap (pointers allocated with 'new' keyword)

this is just some explanations but you should search more before you ask because members will vote down on you.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the copy constructor gets invoked in the following cases:

1. explicit copy construction
2. call by value
3. return by value

The assignment operator is implemented to obliterate an exiting instance's old contents with new ones. As you showcase an example:

```
myClass newInstant;
newInstant = oldInstant;//assignment operator
```

Keep in mind that they work differently. Copy-swap involves in the assignment operator.

Regarding your last question, modern compilers apply copy constructor elision to elide unnecessary copy constructor call.